# Variations on Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

Do mathematicians use variations on the Fibonacci sequence?

I'm thinking specifically about something like this:

Start with three $1s$ and for each consecutive number, add the three previous number

e.g. $1,1,1,3,5,9,17...$

Is this a thing (apparently google doesn't think so)? Also, would it have the same relationship to the golden ratio?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TribonacciNumber.html

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called the [tribonacci series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Tribonacci_numbers).  You can find a lot of them at [OEIS A000213](https://oeis.org/A000213).  The long term growth is the largest root of $r^3=r^2+r+1$, which is about $1.83929$

Answer (score 0):

These are called Tribonacci numbers.  For more information, see http://oeis.org/A000213.